# Going to a section of a page using java script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a webpage with several components that looks like:

```
<div id='someId' ...... />
```

Manually it is possible to go to those sections using

```
<a href="#someId" .....  />
```

How, using es2015 or react or javascript, could be created a function to go to that `<div>` component ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function.

```
document.getElementById('someId').scrollIntoView();
```

**React Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rjzjw4862o))**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => {
    this.ref.scrollIntoView();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Scroll down</button>
        <div style={{ height: 1000 }}>Hello CodeSandbox</div>
        <div style={{ height: 1000 }} ref={ref => (this.ref = ref)}>
          Scroll here
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind installing a 3rd party package, I would suggest trying [**`react-scroll-into-view`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-into-view)